# MVC dynamic validation in bootstrap modal not blocking submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, unobtrusive-validation

I've a dynamic form (bootstrap modal) where I want to use data validation.

Therefor when the modal is being shown I apply the validator in my a script.
This is my jquery/javascript code in the index page for showing the modal

```
$("#btnCreate").on("click", function (e) {
    // hide dropdown if any
    $(e.target).closest('.btn-group').children('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');
    $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
        $('#myModal').modal({
            /*backdrop: 'static',*/ 
            keyboard: true
        }, 'show');

        $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            $('.chzn-select', this).chosen({ width: "inherit", disable_search: true });
            /*$("form").data("validator", null);
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("form"));*/
            var form = $("form") //use more specific selector if you like
            form.removeData("validator").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
        });

        bindForm(this);
    });
    return false;
});

function bindForm(dialog) {
    $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    //Refresh
                    location.reload();
                } else {
                    $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                    bindForm();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

The validation works, but the problem is as follows: 
So when I click on the submit button, without the required fields filled in the form still submits. Instead of blocking the POST and telling the user something is wrong.

This is my create view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class="horizontal-form"})) { 
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
<div class="modal-body">
<fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Naam)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Naam, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Naam)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Omschrijving)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Omschrijving, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Omschrijving, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" id="verstuurFormulier" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</fieldset>
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not stopping the normal submit from happening:

```
function bindForm(dialog) {
    $('form', dialog).submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
           ...
```

This means that you have to manually decide when to submit though. I use the following in some of my projects:

```
$('#myForm').removeData("validator");
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('#myForm'));
if ($('#myForm').valid()) { 
    $('#myForm').submit(); 
}
return false;
```

Comment: Thank you, I already thought it had something to do with the submit function. But my knowledge about js and jQuery are at a bare minimum. I didn't needed the e.preventDefault() since my submit button didn't really made a call. The if statement is the solution for my problem.

Comment: You're welcome. Another thing I neglected to mention: You can also use a normal _button_, and not have to worry about it submitting until you decide to do so (by `.submit()`).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might lie in the line:

> `$("form").data("validator", null);`

I usually use this little snippet (found ofc on StackOverflow, but I do not remember the person to give credit to :( )

```
(function ($) {
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parseDynamicContent = function (selector) {
        //use the normal unobstrusive.parse method
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(selector);

        //get the relevant form
        var form = $(selector).first().closest('form');

        //get the collections of unobstrusive validators, and jquery validators
        //and compare the two
        var unobtrusiveValidation = form.data('unobtrusiveValidation');
        var validator = form.validate();

        $.each(unobtrusiveValidation.options.rules, function (elname, elrules) {
            if (validator.settings.rules[elname] == undefined) {
                var args = {};
                $.extend(args, elrules);
                args.messages = unobtrusiveValidation.options.messages[elname];
                //edit:use quoted strings for the name selector
                $("[name='" + elname + "']").rules("add", args);
            } else {
                $.each(elrules, function (rulename, data) {
                    if (validator.settings.rules[elname][rulename] == undefined) {
                        var args = {};
                        args[rulename] = data;
                        args.messages = unobtrusiveValidation.options.messages[elname][rulename];
                        //edit:use quoted strings for the name selector
                        $("[name='" + elname + "']").rules("add", args);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
})($);
```

Then just delete the null on form validator and change the parse call to:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parseDynamicContent('form');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hm thank you. But this didn't solve my problem. When I replaced my piece of javascript with yours the validation doesn't work at all anymore.